# Remove Many-to-many relations records in database with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

If I have many to many relation ship in database witch is looking like that:

```
House-HouseType-Type
```

In data model it is looking like that

```
House-Type
```

I cant modify table `HouseType` directly because there is no entity for that.

For example if I have insert some entities in database after records in table `HouseType` looking like that:

```
HouseId TypeId
1       2
1       3
1       4
```

than I want to remove some relations records.

e.g Records in table  after remove would be:

```
  HouseId TypeId
    1       2
```

How can I do that in Entity Framework 4 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
house.Types.Remove(type)
```

or

```
type.Houses.Remove(house)
```